# Need a way to make a MySQL query factor in or exclude condition in Where clause based on what conditions are specified or not specified

Tags: mysql

I use Chartio to create dashboards. I'm able to use variables with Chartio that can fill in sections of a MySQL query and then pump out a cool looking graph. I have a situation where I need a query that can have any combination of 3 variables X, Y, Z as shown below.

```
SELECT orderid
FROM orders 
WHERE productcode IN (X) AND
    status IN (Y) AND
    date IN (Z);
```

I need to have the ability for the query to "determine" that if I only give it X, ignore Y and Z as a condition, for example. Or if I give it X and Y, ignore Z. I could give it any combinations of those three.  By "ignore" I mean not use it as a condition in the WHERE clause.

Is this possible using OR? REGEXP? Wildcards? ...? I'm not very well versed in MySQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a programming language like PHP to create the query? If this is done automatically by Chartio, you'll need to consult its documentation to see how to omit criteria that the user doesn't select.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL.

Comment: I meant a procedural language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it sets the variable to an empty string when the user leaves the field out, you can write:

```
SELECT orderid
FROM orders 
WHERE (X = '' OR productcode = X) AND
    (Y = '' OR status = Y) AND
    (Z = '' OR date = Z);
```

Comment: This is on the right track. This works perfectly if I'm only using a single X variable for example. But what if I want to specify multiple X values? Like this for example... 

`SELECT orderid
FROM orders 
WHERE (X = '' OR productcode IN (X,A,B,C) AND
    (Y = '' OR status = Y) AND
    (Z = '' OR date = Z);`

The problem is that the first part `X = ''` only works for single values. Is there a way to tweak that one part? Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE ((X = '' AND A = '' AND B = '' AND C = '') OR productcode IN (X, A, B, C)) AND ...`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help!